# How do you underline selected text in a WinRT RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, richeditbox

I'm currently making an application which includes a rich text editor, however I'm having some issues with applying formatting to the text. Specifically, I'm having an issue with underlining the selected text. Here is my current code.

```
    private void UnderlineButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ITextSelection selectedText = rtfEditor.Document.Selection;
        if (selectedText != null)
        {
            ITextCharacterFormat charFormatting = selectedText.CharacterFormat;
            charFormatting.Underline = UnderlineType.Single;
            //charFormatting.Underline = FormatEffect.;
            selectedText.CharacterFormat = charFormatting;
        }
    }
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
rtfEditor.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Underline = UnderlineType.Thin;
```

or

```
ITextSelection selectedText = rtfEditor.Document.Selection;
selectedText.CharacterFormat.Underline = UnderlineType.Double;
```

Comment: Turns out I was just an idiot and forgot to add a click handler to my underline button >.<